# what is the extension fo sms that are saved in windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

i want to know the folder hierarchy where the sms are saved and what is the extensions of sms files in windows mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think they are stored in the file system as individual files?  They're not.  You can't just open a folder and walk files to get them, you have to use the [Messaging API (MAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx) to open the store and pull them out.

Since you didn't indicate what language you're programming in, [here's an example in C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2007/04/23/practical-use-of-mapi.aspx) that pulls out SMS messages and saves them to a file.